# Switching between arabic, roman and alph frame numbering

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I just wonder how can I easily switch to arabic, roman or alph frame numbering between frames?

I don't want to use `\appendix`! I want, for instance: three slides in arabic numbering, then two slides in alph, then two slides in arabic, then three slides in roman, etc.

Is it possible?

Comment: There are many classes/packages that use frames. It would help if you could provide some more information. A minimum working example, would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of the current frame is contained in the counter

```
framenumber
```

which is output by the command

```
\theframenumber
```

Unless you don't want to write wrapper code for frames with arabic, alph or roman 'numbering', you have to redefine the `\theframenumber` command each time you want to have a specific numbering.

```
\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\alph{framenumber}} % for lower case letters
\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\arabic{framenumber}} % for arabic numbering
\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\Roman{framenumber}} % for upcase roman numbering.
```

Don't forget to set the `framenumber` counter to zero, if you want to restart the counting, unless you prefer, say, frame 5 followed by 'F' etc.

For future use wrapper environments with an optional `[framenumberstyle=Roman]` etc. would help.

Here is a MWE in which I omitted any further feature of the `beamer` class and did reset the counter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

%%% Now upper case ('Alph')  numbering
\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\Alph{framenumber}}

\begin{frame}[label=first]{Frame Number One with upper case numbering}
This is frame number \theframenumber
\end{frame}

 \begin{frame}[label=second_alph]{Frame Number Two with upper case numbering}
This is frame number \theframenumber
\end{frame}

%%% Now arabic numbering

\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\arabic{framenumber}}
\begin{frame}[label=first_arabic]{Frame Number Three with arabic numbering}

This is frame number \theframenumber
\end{frame}

%%% Now Roman numbering
\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\Roman{framenumber}}
\begin{frame}[label=first_roman]{Frame Number Four with roman numbering}

This is frame number \theframenumber
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[label=second_roman]{Frame Number Five with roman numbering}
This is frame number \theframenumber

\end{frame}

\end{document}% End
```

**Edit 2015/01/02**

Some themes use the outer theme `infoline` which uses a 'frame number/totalframenumber' output in the lower right part.

The frame number is inserted by `\insertframenumber`, which itself is

`\arabic{framenumber}`

so this has to be changed to another counting format (at will)

To get rid of the total frame number it's necessary to change the 
beamer template footline after the line

`\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}`

The spacing command after `\insertframenumber` is deliberately used (change to appropiate values)

```
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\Roman{framenumber}} % Upper case roman numbers

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{patched infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \rlap{\insertframenumber} \hspace*{1ex}%
    \hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It work fine for plain slide but when I use theme **Madrid**, the slide number is still in **Arabic** number. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: @OLSAY: See my update

Comment: It works now :)

Comment: @OLSAY: Yes, it works now, after some more information -- the OP did not even specify what he means/which beamer theme, so my answer as a general one.

Comment: Frankly I have jut tested theme **Madrid**. It works for the current page of each frame. There is a little bit to fix for the last page. Anyway, I can fix it :)

Comment: @OLSAY: Well, it worked in the small test document I posted originally, even for the last frame